# Scraped table returns empty data frame

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping, rvest

I'm trying to scrape two things. I want to extract the links from each individual school on a page with this code:

```
scraped_links <- read_html("https://www.scholenopdekaart.nl/middelbare-scholen/zoeken/") %>%
  html_nodes("a.school-naam") %>%
  html_attr("href") %>%
  html_table() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  as.tbl()
```

Then I want to scrape the tabels on these pages:

```
scraped_tables <- read_html("https://www.scholenopdekaart.nl/Middelbare-scholen/146/1086/Almere-College/Slaagpercentage") %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/div[3]") %>%
  html_table() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  as.tbl()
```

They both return empty data frames. I tried css selectors, multiple xpaths, but I can't get it to work... Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You need to use some headless browser scraper, as it's a JS generated table.

Comment: Try `//table[@class="a184"]` and `//table[@class="a110"]` to get the tables.